# Evaluate the indefinite integral $\int\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)\ dx$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, inverse

> Integrate $\int\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}.dx$

$$\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=\begin{cases}2\tan^{-1}x&\text{ if }|x|\leq{1}\\\pi-2\tan^{-1}x&\text{ if }|x|>{1}&\text{ and }x>0\\-\pi-2\tan^{-1}x&\text{ if }|x|>{1}&\text{ and }x<0\end{cases}$$

$$
\int\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}.dx=\begin{cases}\int2\tan^{-1}xdx&\text{ if }|x|\leq{1}\\\int\pi dx-\int2\tan^{-1}xdx&\text{ if }|x|>{1}&\text{ and }x>0\\-\int\pi dx-\int2\tan^{-1}xdx&\text{ if }|x|>{1}&\text{ and }x<0\end{cases}=\begin{cases}2x\tan^{-1}x-\log(1+x^2)+C&\text{ if }|x|\leq{1}\\\pi x-2x\tan^{-1}x-\log(1+x^2)+C&\text{ if }|x|>{1}&\text{ and }x>0\\-\pi x-2x\tan^{-1}x-\log(1+x^2)+C&\text{ if }|x|>{1}&\text{ and }x<0\end{cases}$$

How do I obtain the case by case result for this type of indefinite integral ?

I tried

```
Integrate[ArcSin[2*x/(1 + x^2)], x]
```

which is not giving the required result.

Comment: Is $\sin^{-1}x$ supposed to be $\asin x$? That would be really helpful to differentiate from $(\sin x) ^{-1}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk pls check the edits . I tried that, but it doesnt seem to give a case by case solution.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP $\sin^{-1}\equiv\arcsin$

Comment: Many would disagree :-)

Comment: Probably is not exactly what you were looking for, but you can try breaking the integral in the three different cases:
FullSimplify[Integrate[ArcSin[(2 x)/(1 + x^2)], x], -1 <= x <= 1]
FullSimplify[Integrate[ArcSin[(2 x)/(1 + x^2)], x], x > 1]
FullSimplify[Integrate[ArcSin[(2 x)/(1 + x^2)], x], x < -1]

Comment: @LLlAMnYP why 'd that be ?. $(\sin x)^{-1}$ is not same as $\sin^{-1}x$. Rather $(\sin x)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sin x}$ and $\sin^{-1}x=\arcsin x$. I think this is how it is commonly defined.

Comment: Are you sure that the formulae you give are correct? I tried to verify the first case, of the first piecewise function and it does not seem to be working in Mathematica.

Comment: We're going way off topic, but see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Pythagorean_identities) where $\sin^2x \equiv (\sin x)^2$ and not $\sin (\sin x)$. This is extremely common notation. This issue is explicitly discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Note_on_notation).

Answer (score 7):

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[ArcSin[(2 x)/(1 + x^2)], TargetFunctions->{Re, Im}], x ∈ Reals]
Integrate[% /. Abs -> RealAbs, x]
% // Simplify
Resolve[ForAll[x, Evaluate[ArcSin[(2 x)/(1 + x^2)] == D[%, x]]], Reals]
```

> ArcTan[Abs[-1 + x^2], 2 x]
>
> $\begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  x \tan ^{-1}\left(x^2-1,2 x\right)+\log \left(x^2+1\right) & x\leq -1 \\
>  x \tan ^{-1}\left(1-x^2,2 x\right)-\log \left(x^2+1\right)+2 \log (2) & -1<x\leq 1 \\
>  x \tan ^{-1}\left(x^2-1,2 x\right)+\log \left(x^2+1\right) & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}$
>
> $\begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  x \tan ^{-1}\left(1-x^2,2 x\right)-\log \left(x^2+1\right)+\log (4) & -1<x\leq 1 \\
>  x \tan ^{-1}\left(x^2-1,2 x\right)+\log \left(x^2+1\right) & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}$
>
> True

Another way:
$$\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=\begin{cases}2\tan^{-1}x&\text{ if }|x|\leq{1}\\\pi-2\tan^{-1}x&\text{ if }|x|>{1}&\text{ and }x>0\\-\pi-2\tan^{-1}x&\text{ if }|x|>{1}&\text{ and }x<0\end{cases}=\begin{cases}2\tan^{-1}x&\text{ if }|x|\leq{1}\\2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)&\text{ if }x > 1&\text{or }  x < -1\end{cases}$$
This can be verified with Mathematica

```
FullSimplify[π - 2 ArcTan[x] == 2 ArcTan[1/x], {Abs[x] > 1, x > 0}]
FullSimplify[-π - 2 ArcTan[x] == 2 ArcTan[1/x], {Abs[x] > 1, x < 0}]
Reduce[(Abs[x] > 1 && x > 0) || (Abs[x] > 1 && x < 0), x, Reals]
```

> True
>
> True
>
> x < -1 || x > 1

```
expr = ArcSin[(2 x)/(1 + x^2)];
sol = Solve[Reduce[{y == expr}, x, Reals] // Simplify, y, Reals(*,MaxExtraConditions -> All*)]
pw = y /. sol /. ConditionalExpression -> List // Piecewise
int = Integrate[pw, x] // Simplify
Resolve[ForAll[x, Evaluate[expr == D[int, x]]], Reals]
```

> {{y -> ConditionalExpression[2 ArcTan[1/x], x > 1 || x < -1]},
>
> {y -> ConditionalExpression[2 ArcTan[x], -1 < x < 0 || 0 < x < 1]}}
>
> $\begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -\log \left(x^2+1\right)+2 x \tan ^{-1}(x)+\log (4) & -1<x\leq 1 \\
>  \log \left(x^2+1\right)+2 x \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}$
>
> True

Comment: If you want to avoid conversion to `RealAbs`, you can do `Assuming[x ∈ Reals, 
 PiecewiseExpand[
  FullSimplify[
   ComplexExpand[ArcSin[(2 x)/(1 + x^2)], 
    TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]]]` and then `Integrate[%, x]` gives a piecewise result with 3 terms.